# Id combined of Expression and Literal String

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is it possible to make id with expression and literal string?

Like if I have an attribute called ownerId and I want the div to have `id="ownerIdvalue+appendedString"`

For example, if my ownerId value is 345ABC and the div id to have a string 'New' following the ownerIdvalue. I know I can make the div id to be the same as the attribute value by `<div id='{!v.ownerId}'`, but not sure how to make the div id to be `'345ABCNew'.`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out after multiple times modifying the id. This works

```
 <div id="{!'New' + v.ownerId}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make whatever "id" you want for non-managed elements, including from merge fields. This is acceptable:

```
<div id="{!owner.name}{!somevalue}">...
```

For managed elements-- those that start with a namespace like `apex` or `c`, you must use literal values.

Comment: that syntax doesn't work for some reasons.
I got it to work by using  <div id="{!'New' + v.ownerId}"></div>